# Creating a new line in MainActivity of android studio

Tags: android

I have an List of events that I want to display in a TextView I have tried doing it multiple ways with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, `\n`, `\r\n` I have tried a few other ways but it doesnt do anything when I run the emulator it is still the same.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Event event:events) 
    {
        s = event.getData();
        sb.append(s + "\n");
    }
eventText1.setText(sb);
```

Is there any other way to doing it? Am I missing something?

Any help is welcome :) thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a full code sample? What exactly are you setting to TextView?

Comment: I added the code into my question, I'm trying to set a for loop that prints array data on a separate line.

Comment: Does it work if you set the text manually to multiple lines? E.g. in XML
android:text="Test \nNewLine \nAnotherNew Line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your TextView **don't set single line mode (android:singleLine="true" or android:maxLines="1") and height is WRAP_PARENT**. Example:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prompt_description"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
```

In your java file:

```
String text = "Line 1"
text_description.setText(text + "\n Line 2" + "\n Line 3" + "...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListView for displaying things in a list.. or else u can use 
TextView itself..

```
String some_string="Bla Bla";
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(whatever);
textView.setText(some_string + "\n");
```

this is how u can add separator in a TextView.. for more details pls provide your code.. :)

Comment: I added the code to my question, I have the exact same TextView like you do, but when I run the emulator no new line is created.